# Display label name in the Index Scaffold template (using attributes)

Tags: c#, templates, attributes, crud

I'm using the CRUD templates in MVC3 and I would like to make the index/list as intelligent as the others (create,delete,edit,detail). The list template hardcodes the property name instead of showing the attribute display name.

So if I have these properties:

```csharp
[Display(Name="First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Display(Name="Last Name")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Is there a simple way to modify the index/list template and have something like this in the grid header columns?

```
@Html.LabelFor(item.FirstName)
```

If not, I'm sure it is at least possible to get the **attribute display name** instead of the **property name**.